# Make NSOpenPanel open a custom directory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

is there any way that I can pass a URL to a folder on my system which should be the default window which an NSOpenPanel opens?
Thanks!

Update:

```
NSOpenPanel *ads_open = [[NSOpenPanel openPanel] retain];
[ads_open setDirectoryURL:"file://localhost/System/Library/CoreServices/prndrv"];
```

I am using the above code which is the directory which I would like to be opened by default. However, the default window that I am getting is still the last one that I have accessed and not the one that I have specified. How can I access the URL directory?

Comment: How could this even work. `setDirectoryURL:` takes an NSURL not a Char* ...

Comment: So what should I add for the path to be seen as an NSURL?

Comment: [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://your/path/here"]

Answer (score 2):

```
NSOpenPanel *ads_open = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[ads_open setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/System/Library/CoreServices/prndrv"]];
```

Answer (score 2):

beware to use `[NSURL fileURLWithPath:someStringPath]` else its not a valid file url:

```
   NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

// changes promt to Select
[panel setPrompt:@"Select"];

// Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
[panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];

// Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
[panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];

//allows multi select
[panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
if(exists){
    [panel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:lastPath]];
}

[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window
              completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode) {
                  if (returnCode == NSOKButton)
                  {
                      .....

              }}];
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 3:

```
let panel = NSOpenPanel()
panel.directoryURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "smb://servername/path", isDirectory: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Working example:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[panel setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/System/Library/CoreServices/"]];

[panel beginSheetModalForWindow:self.window
              completionHandler:^(NSInteger returnCode) {
                  if (returnCode == NSOKButton)
                  {
                      NSURL *theURL = [[panel URLs] objectAtIndex:0];
                  }
              }];
```

Comment: This is the line that should be doing the trick but for some reason isn't...


 [ads_open setDirectoryURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/System/Library/CoreServices/HOBmacgate/prndrv"]];

The file browser is still loading the last URL that was accessed and not the default one specified as a URL.

Comment: Are you sure `/localhost/System/Library/CoreServices/HOBmacgate/prndrv` actually exists? Otherwhise `NSOpenPanel` cannot display the directory.